# Scaling up/down images of multiple divs with the same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, class, html

I have this code to shrink/grow images so they fit the parent div:

```
<script src="js/imgscale.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('img.profilepicture').imgscale({ 
    parent : '.ppparent', 
    fade : 1000 
  }); 
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly for one div with one class name, but stops working for all of them (i.e. no images are changed) when I try to use it with many divs with the same class names.

How can I "fix" this?

Comment: Are all image class name same as `profilepicture`?

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/A3vh4/ working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your images with class `.profilepicture`

```
   $("img.profilepicture").each(function(){
       $(this).imgscale({ 
             parent : '.ppparent', 
             fade : 1000 
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function for each of the images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('img.profilepicture').each(function() {
        $(this).imgscale({ 
            parent : '.ppparent', 
            fade : 1000 
          }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me. Do you have iMessage/Skype so I can send you a link to the page? Thanks.

Comment: I added a log inside `$('img.profilepicture').each(function()` and it only got called once. There are about 4 divs and imgs so something's not working properly...